# Adding multiple options in against single column in GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, hasura

I am trying to make a query where I can add filters with multiple options. I currently have this query

```
query FacilitiesQuery(
    $limit: Int
    $offset: Int
    $query: String
    $sort: [facilities_order_by!]
  ) {
    facilities(
      limit: $limit
      offset: $offset
      where: {
        _or: [
          { name: { _ilike: $query } },
          { location: { _ilike: $query } },
        ]
        _and: [
          { deleted_at: { _is_null: true } },
          { status_id: { _eq: 1 } }
        ]
      }
      order_by: $sort
    ) {
      id
      location
      name
      status_id
      updated_at
      created_at
      area
      floor
      handover_condition
      handover_meter
      handover_office
      lcd
      level
      move_in_date
      rcd
      company_id
      deleted_at
      expiry_date
      area_type
      building_name
      enum_area_type {
        id
        name
      }
    }
    enum_facility_statuses {
      id
      value
    }
    facilities_aggregate(where: { deleted_at: { _is_null: true } }) {
      aggregate {
        count
      }
    }
  }
```

I am trying to query by `status_id`. I am trying to implement a filter on front-end which can fetch all the checked options based on a modal with a checkbox.

For example I want to fetch records with status_id 1 and 2, I am looking for something like this

```
_and: [
  { deleted_at: { _is_null: true } },
  { status_id: { _eq: [1,2] } }
]
```

But I am not able to execute them. I need help in modifying this query such way.

Comment: it's not only frontend ... api has to support all your needs ... `eq` ususally means ONE value

Comment: I am beginner, I don't really know how to add it to API

Comment: I mean GQL doesn't have support for this? I can modify my query if I have to. I just need to filter based on statuses.

Comment: GQL standard doesn't define that (filtering at all) - it's implementation related ... read docs.... `_in` for set ? nested `_or` (id eq 1 or id eq 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you need to specify the correct type, auto generated by Hasura.  In the Hasura console, GraphiQL tab, there is a documentation explorer tab.  There you can see the types generated by Hasura for each query.

[image: HasuraQueryExplorer]

You will need to check in your Hasura console, but your query should be something like:

```js
query FacilitiesQuery(
    $limit: Int
    $offset: Int
    $where: facilities_bool_exp!
    $sort: [facilities_order_by!]
  ) {
    facilities(
      limit: $limit
      offset: $offset
      where: $where
      }
      order_by: $sort
    ) {
      id
      location
      name
      status_id
      updated_at
      created_at
      area
      floor
      handover_condition
      handover_meter
      handover_office
      lcd
      level
      move_in_date
      rcd
      company_id
      deleted_at
      expiry_date
      area_type
      building_name
      enum_area_type {
        id
        name
      }
    }
    enum_facility_statuses {
      id
      value
    }
    facilities_aggregate(where: { deleted_at: { _is_null: true } }) {
      aggregate {
        count
      }
    }
  }
```

and you can build the where as needed.

Comment: Yes, so far I am following the documentation. But I am not really able to find if I have to add _or or _and for a single field. I can change the query if I have to